# Is there a way to exclude empty cells in a nested countif formula with importranges?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a nested formula that is counting empty cells. The formula is counting between 2 date columns by user ID for any dates that are within 7 days.

The formula is counting between 2 date columns by user ID for any dates that are within 7 days. I have tried to add an `ISBLANK` and also say to exclude any cells within the 2 columns that are empty.

Here is the formula that currently works but still includes empty cells.

```
=COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(DAYS(FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("SPREADSHEET_URL","Main!P2:P"),IMPORTRANGE("SPREADSHEET_URL","Main!N2:N")=A20),FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("SPREADSHEET_URL","Main!O2:O"),IMPORTRANGE("SPREADSHEET_URL","Main!N2:N")=A20))),"<=7")
```

Can you help find a way to exclude empty cells?

Comment: Why can't you use a countifs that adds a condition to exclude blanks?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
=COUNTIFS(ARRAYFORMULA(DAYS(FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("SPREADSHEET_URL","Main!P2:P"),IMPORTRANGE("SPREADSHEET_URL","Main!N2:N")=A20),FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("SPREADSHEET_URL","Main!O2:O"),IMPORTRANGE("SPREADSHEET_URL","Main!N2:N")=A20))),"<=7",ARRAYFORMULA(DAYS(FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("SPREADSHEET_URL","Main!P2:P"),IMPORTRANGE("SPREADSHEET_URL","Main!N2:N")=A20),FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("SPREADSHEET_URL","Main!O2:O"),IMPORTRANGE("SPREADSHEET_URL","Main!N2:N")=A20))),"<>")
```